# TableCellRenderer with too small column has no dots suffix

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I try to learn the JTables TableCellRenderer and there is something I don't understand. Maybe one of you can help me.

Please have a look on this example I found on the Web:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/implementsTableCellRenderer.htm

It is a simple compilable unit to demonstrate the use of a TableCellRenderer.

But now, with a defined Renderer, when I shrink the columns the titles are still trunk and get a ending "...".
The values are only "hidden", because there is not enough space. The "..." are missing.
Please see the image .

[image]

Is there a possibility to get the "..." for the value cells?

Comment: What's the code for the `TableCellRenderer`, cause it don't look like the default...

Comment: That's a doubtful example from the very fact it creates a .. `JTextField editor = new JTextField();` every time the get cell renderer method is called.  Then there is that it uses a text field rather than the (default) `JLabel` for no apparent reason.. Your best bet is to use examples form the [Swing tutorial on renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

Comment: @MadProgrammer  It is a text field (from a terrible example).

Comment: As an aside.  Check out the default [table in the Nimbus PLAF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0okxX.png) if you want 'alternate color rows'.  Nimbus implements that automatically..

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's what I figured, just wanted to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as others commented, your cell renderer returns a `JTextField`.
in swing, this clip string implementation is there in the class called `SwingUtilities2`.

```
public static String clipString(JComponent var0, FontMetrics var1, String var2, int var3)
```

But this clip string logic will be used by some components only.
ex: Button, RadioButton, TabPane, MenuItem, Label.

Comment: Thanks - but than I don't understand, why the strings are clipped if no Renderer is set. So sure, without Renderer or with JLabels it works. Good to know. But in my Project I would have both. Any idea how to add this logic to a (self defined) TextField?

Comment: "No renderer" means if we haven't specified the renderer. then table will be initialized with  DefaultTableCellRenderer which is a subclass of JLabel. i cant see any good reason to use a TextField as a renderer. could u pls be more specific about the requirement?

Comment: My Problem is, that I have a quite complicated structure with different subclasses of TextField. So it would be easier to extend the TextField this Behavior, if it would be possible.